# Aggregating multiple columns into one in Pandas quickly

Tags: python, pandas, shapely

I have a DataFrame that is, ultimately, object IDs attached to individual X and Y coordinates, something like

| ID | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 7 | 1 |
| 2 | 8 | 5 |
| 2 | 9 | 7 |

I ultimately have no guarantee about order of IDs or X/Y, and can't make these connected upstream.

With the ultimate goal of getting a convex hull of the points involved, I'm currently grouping the X/Ys into a list, then zipping them, then changing that list-of-tuples to a Shapely `MultiPoint` before finding the convex hull.

```
import shapely.geometry as shGeom
sf = df.groupby("ID").agg({"X": list, "Y": list})
# I want to keep this coordinate set for later, though as the MultiPoint would be fine.
# In tests, storing the MultiPoint as an intermediate is slower due to memory pressure 
# rather than the list-of-tuples
sf["coordinates"] = shapeFrame[["Y", "X"]].apply(lambda x: [(a,b) for a, b in zip(x[0], x[1])], axis= 1)
# This next "hull" column is the target
sf["hull"] = sf["coordinates"].apply(lambda x: shGeom.MultiPoint(x).convex_hull)
```

This approach though requires several data passes over a 1M+ row frame, and in particular the zipping pass is slow.

Is there a way to do this with fewer data passes? It feels like there should be. (At the end of the day this code *works* but this is a very slow step in it)

I do use GeoPandas later, but there's no geometry column to operate upon until the X and Y entries are turned into `Point` s or a `MultiPolygon`, which doesn't get around the slow step.

Comment: So basically what you want to do is find the convex hull for each set of points grouped by Id?

Comment: Use geopandas is the way to go

Comment: I use GeoPandas later, but a geometry column can't exist until I group those points and turn it into a MultiPoint (they're computed, so they never exist beforehand).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scipy` function to calculate the Convex Hull

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

grouped = df.groupby('ID')

def compute_hull(group):
    points = group[['X', 'Y']].values
    hull = ConvexHull(points)
    return {'ID': group.name, 'hull': hull}

convex_hulls = grouped.apply(compute_hull).tolist()

print(convex_hulls)
```

I tried this in a dummy `df` I created with 1 million rows and it runs instantly.

Comment: Actually slower than my current method for my real dataset =/